# Importing Javadoc documentation on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am new to Eclipse, I am using OWL API from Protege and I would like to import to this IDE its Javadoc documentation which is accessible online in html format. How do I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right-click your jar, choose `Properties`. Choose `Javadoc location`. Enter the URL in `Javadoc location path`.